# Why does this plot not work when changing variable range?

Tags: plotting, functions

This works.

```
Plot[ConditionalExpression[2 - 3 x, 1/3 <= x <= 1/2], {x, -3, 3}]
```

[image]

But if you change the range it does not work.

```
Plot[ConditionalExpression[2 - 3 x, 1/3 <= x <= 1/2], {x, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

According to help, `ConditionalExpression[expr,False] evaluates to Undefined.`  so in theory, the plot should have worked only when `1/3 <= x <= 1/2` for both cases.

It seems related to sampling points. By increasing it, it will work

```
ce = ConditionalExpression[2 - 3 x, 1/3 <= x <= 1/2];
Plot[ce, {x, -3, 3}]
Plot[ce, {x, -5, 5}]
```

give

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But now

```
Plot[ce, {x, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 40]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

At `PlotPoints` of `10,20,30` it gives blank plot.

At `PlotPoints` of `40` it works.

This seems be an issue internal to Plot, where if it finds too many `Undefined` results, it gives up.

By increasing the sampling points, this avoids this issue. But I am not sure. Just a theory.

**Update**

The above theory is wrong. I found the `PlotPoints` used is `50` by default. So this now gives blank plot

```
Plot[ce, {x, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So it is *not* the increasing of `PlotPoints` which fixes it, but the *specific value* which fixes this issues.

This could be a **bug** in `Plot`. It is related to where the sampling location and the `Undefined` result that shows up from the `ConditionalExpression`

For example, `PlotPoints` at `49` it works. But not at `50` then it works again at `51`.

Comment: I see. Probably it is a bug as you said.